# Processing - Image array error - "Type mismatch, 'processing .core.PImage' does not match.."

Tags: java, arrays, image, processing, type-mismatch

I'm trying to load images into an array in the `void setup()`, but when I do it gives me this error: "Type mismatch, 'processing .core.PImage' does not match 'processing.core.PImage'. Any idea what this means and how to fix it? Here's my simplified code:

```
PImage [] goodCandy = new PImage [3];
int rand=(int) (2*Math.random()) +1;

void setup() {
for (int i=0; i<goodCandy.length; i++) {
  goodCandy = loadImage ("goodCandy" + i + ".png");
}
}
void draw() {
if (current=="play") {
loadStuff();
}
}
void loadStuff() {
image(goodCandy[rand], 0, 0, 50, 50);
}
```

I basically want to generate a random candy from the array and have it appear, but I get this error. I have all 3 images in the folder named goodCandy1, 2, 3.png. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: can you share your imports for the code as well please. And also the implementation of `loadImage` method

Comment: My guess is that the type returned from the `loadImage` method is different than the component type of `goodCandy`. This could be because you have multiple files with the name `PImage`, yet in different projects. However, to start, just provide the imports and the `loadImage` method.

Comment: @nullpointer Please note the [tag:processing] tag, and that [Processing != Java](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/processing-java). Specifically, the `loadImage()` function is internal to Processing.

Comment: Shameless self-promotion: please see [this tutorial](http://HappyCoding.io/tutorials/processing/arrays) on using arrays in Processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`goodCandy[i] = loadImage("goodCandy" + i + ".png");`

The mismatch occurred because you tried to store `PImage` in `PImage[]`.
remember that `loadImage()` returns a `PImage` and not an array of `PImage`, i.e., `PImage[]`